# Show that sets are pairwise disjoint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B \subset X$. Show that the sets $A$ \ $B$, $B$ \ $A$, $A \cap B \subset X$ are pairwise disjoint and that their union is $A \cup B$.

I know that $A$ \ $B$ is $A \cap B^{c}$ and I can write  $B$ \ $A$ as $B \cap A^{c}$, but how can I show that they are pairwise disjoint?

Comment: Suppose they intersect, take an element in the intersection, and see that there is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any shortcut, sorry.

By definition, $A\setminus B=\{x\in X\mid x\in A \wedge x\notin B\}$ and $B\setminus A=\{x\in X\mid x\in
B \wedge x\notin A\}$. As far as the disjointnesses concerns, note that:

1. $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (B\setminus A)$; then, $(x\in A \wedge x\notin B)\wedge (x\in B \wedge
   x\notin A)$, which is equivalent to $(x\in A \wedge x\notin A)\wedge (x\in B \wedge x\notin B)$: false;
   then, $(A\setminus B)\cap (B\setminus A)=\emptyset$.
2. $x\in (A\setminus B)\cap (A\cap B)$; then, $(x\in A \wedge x\notin B)\wedge (x\in A \wedge x\in B)$,
   which is equivalent to $(x\in A) \wedge (x\in B\wedge x\notin B)$: false; then, $(A\setminus B)\cap (A\cap
   B)=\emptyset$.
3. $x\in (B\setminus A)\cap (A\cap B)$; then, $(x\in B \wedge x\notin A)\wedge (x\in A \wedge x\in B)$,
   which is equivalent to $(x\in B) \wedge (x\in A\wedge x\notin A)$: false; then, $(B\setminus A)\cap (A\cap
   B)=\emptyset$.

Moreover:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A) &= \{x\in X\mid (x\in A \wedge x\notin B) \vee (x\in B \wedge x\notin
A) \} \\
&= \{x\in X\mid [(x\in A \wedge x\notin B) \vee (x\in B)] \wedge [(x\in A \wedge x\notin B) \vee (x\notin A)]
\} \\
&= \{x\in X\mid [(x\in B\vee x\in A)\wedge (x\in B\vee x\notin B)] \wedge [(x\notin A\vee x\in A)\wedge
(x\notin A\vee x\notin B)] \} \\
&= \{x\in X\mid (x\in B\vee x\in A) \wedge (x\notin A\vee x\notin B) \} \\
&= \{x\in X\mid (x\in B\vee x\in A) \wedge \neg(x\in A\wedge x\in B) \} \\
&= (A\cup B)\cap (X\setminus (A\cap B)) \\
\end{alignat}

whence:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A) \cup (A\cap B) &= [(A\cup B)\cap (X\setminus (A\cap B))]\cup (A\cap B) \\
&= [(A\cap B)\cup (A\cup B)]\cap [(A\cap B)\cup (X\setminus (A\cap B))] \\
&= (A\cup B)\cap X \\
&= A\cup B
\end{alignat}

Comment: Thank you so so much for this detailed answer! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is some $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap (B\setminus A)$. Then $x \in A \setminus B$ and $x \in B \setminus A$. So, $x \in A$ and $x\notin A$. By contradiction $(A \setminus B) \cap (B\setminus A)=\emptyset$. Try a similar reasoning for the other cases.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome ;)